# wget for ftp using a password containing @

Tags: ftp, wget

I am trying to get some files from my ftp server from the command line. I am using wget to download the whole folder at once. The command is:

```
wget -m ftp://username:password@ftp.hostname.com:/path/to/folder
```

But the problem is, my password contains the '@' symbol. Hence The command becomes

```
wget -m ftp://username:foo@bar@ftp.hostname.com:/..
```

due to which, wget tries to resove bar@ftp.hostname.com as the host, which it is not able to. Please help!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Rather than the `user:pass@hostname` syntax, use switches. From `wget --help`:

```
--ftp-user=USER         set ftp user to USER.
--ftp-password=PASS     set ftp password to PASS.
```

Example:

```
wget -m --ftp-user=username --ftp-password=foo@bar ftp://ftp.hostname.com/file
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also URL encode the username and/or password. The `@` symbol becomes `%40`

For example:

```
wget -m ftp://username:foo@bar@ftp.hostname.com:/..
```

can be written as

```
wget -m ftp://username:foo%40bar@ftp.hostname.com:/..
```

I realize this question has been solved long ago, but I saw this in the corner of my eye and thought I'd throw in a solution (this is actually useful, because it should work with anything that uses or supports using URIs, such as FileZilla or a web browser.)

Answer (score -2):

wget -m --ftp-user=username --ftp-password=foo@bar ftp://ftp.hostname.com/file -O /path_to_file/dest_file_name

Comment: Duplicates an answer given 3 years ago...